# removing subfolder name and file extension from url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to remove the seo/ folder name and the file extension(.html) from the below url. I am working on a static html website.

**www.example.com/seo/advanced-system.html** to **www.example.com/advanced-system/**

In .htaccess of my **root** folder I have written this,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^seo/(.*)$ www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In .htaccess of my **subfolder** I have written this,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I googled and tried all possible ways, but not able to find the solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .htaccess of my root folder, use this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!seo/).*)$ seo/$1 [L,NC]
```

In .htaccess of `/seo/`, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /seo/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/seo/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: its not working... css is removed completely and even in the url "seo" is not removed...

Comment: See updated answer. You must enter `http://domain.com/file` and it will load `http://domain.com/seo/file.html`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really working good. But even if we enter http://www.domain.com/seo/file.html, it should load www.domain.com/file/. Can we change like that?

Comment: Thanks Anubhava... This solution is not working. The previous edit is working good for me and also I made the changes in my links to make it work properly. Can you please edit it, so that i can mark the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        RewriteEngine On 
        RewriteRule ^$ seo/ 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ seo/$1
```