# How to hide folder names and file extension in URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have following requirements which i believe can be accomplished using .htaccess file.
**Requirements-**

1. Hide Folder names and file extension in URL Eg. `www.example.com/subfolder/subfolder1/file.php` should become `www.example.com/file`
2. Restrict Folder browsing - I want to restrict folder browsing capability when somebody fires an URL eg. `www.example.com/subfolder` Conventionally by firing this URL user will be able to browse through the contents of `subfolder`. By firing such URL or any URL containing domain `example.com` eg. `www.example.com/folderNotExist` then server should redirect to index page.

I am able to restrict folder browsing but redirection to index page and hiding of folder and file extension is not working.

Comment: please add the rules you've tried that don't work

Comment: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366605/removing-subfolder-name-and-file-extension-from-url-using-htaccess?rq=1'
This is the page i took help from. I do not have the exact script right now. Since it did not worked i deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subfolder/subfolder1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/subfolder1/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ subfolder/subfolder1/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /subfolder/subfolder1/$1.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: It is NOT working. I have put my `.htaccess` file at root location i.e.e where my `index.php` resides.
Infact what it does is that it restricts access to `index.php` aswell unless i type `localhost/dashboard/index.php`
It is then neither satisfying requirement 1 as well as requirement 2

Comment: @VishalKhare you will need to clear your browser history and then force refresh the page to active the updated `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysample.com
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://www.mysample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```